# Using variables sent from script into html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Been trying for a while to send variables using url like this:

```
$.post("Controlador.php",{Ema:email_usuario, Cont:pass_usuario,Acc: acc}, 
function(datos){
                 json = JSON.parse(datos);
                 var Nombres = json.Nombres;
                 var Cedula = json.Cedula;
                 location.href = "Acerca.html proced="+Nombres+"&proce="+Cedula;
```

Now, it actually works sending the variables into the new page [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVaj8.png), but I can't seem to find a way to use these variables and I was wondering if anyone could help out. Thank you.

Edit: Alright, I managed to make it work... slightly (Still very new at this). I managed to use the variables (in this case the name "Martin") and display it almost as intended.  [This was the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCpfm.png). As you can see, it has a weird %20 which I don't know how it got there. Any ideas about how to remove it? Thanks a lot. Below I display what I used for this:

```
<script>

    function getUrlVars(){   
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    //Calling function gerUrlVars to get value from url
    function volar(){
    var proce= getUrlVars()["proce"];
    var proced= getUrlVars()["proced"];
    document.getElementById("sirve").innerHTML = proced; 
    }

</script>

</head>
<body onload="volar();">
```

Comment: `find a way to use these variables` ?? Just reference them and use them however you like, pass them around, etc

Comment: How familiar are you with PHP? I see that you are sending a GET request to an HTML file. (except if you configured your server to execute .html files as PHP)

Answer (score 0):

get value from URL

```
function getUrlVars()
{   
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

//Calling function gerUrlVars to get value from url
var proce= getUrlVars()["proce"];
var proced= getUrlVars()["proced"];
```

Now you can use proce and proced .

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly new at this. May I ask why is there a need for both proce and proced? Isn't just one enough?

Comment: It's depend on your need , I don't know what do you want to do next with these variable .

Comment: Made an edit that explains a little better what the problem currently is.